# Upload file from my virtual machine to another virtual machine using hadoop hdfs

Tags: hadoop, upload

Can any one please tell me, how can I upload a txt file from my local machine to another virtual machine based on IP Address in hdfs.

Regards,
Lokesh G

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy file to hadoop machine using

```
scp copy-file.txt user_name@hadoop-machine:/path
```

Replace the keywords with actual values

After copying file u can simply upload files on HDFS using

```
hadoop fs -put copy-file.txt /hdfs-path
```